# Customising meta_form() in wp-admin/includes/template.php

Tags: wordpress

Hi all I'm a WordPress noob so please bear with me. So in template.php I need the functionality of the `meta_form()` function to change based on a few conditions. Here's what it looks like:

Original code:

```
    function meta_form() {
        global $wpdb;
        $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
        $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
            SELECT meta_key
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            GROUP BY meta_key
            HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
            ORDER BY meta_key
            LIMIT $limit" );
        if ( $keys )
            natcasesort($keys);
    ?>
```

Customized version:

```
function meta_form() {
    global $wpdb;

  if ( isset($_GET['post']) )
    $post_id = (int) $_GET['post'];
  elseif ( isset($_POST['post_ID']) )
    $post_id = (int) $_POST['post_ID'];
  else
    $post_id = 0;

  if ( $post_id ) {
    $post_ = get_post($post_id);

  }

  if ($post_->post_type == 'video_photo' ){
    $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
    $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        where meta_key like 'tqmcf_%'
        GROUP BY meta_key
        HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
        ORDER BY meta_key
        LIMIT $limit" );
  }else{
    $limit = (int) apply_filters( 'postmeta_form_limit', 30 );
    $keys = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT meta_key
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        GROUP BY meta_key
        HAVING meta_key NOT LIKE '\_%'
        ORDER BY meta_key
        LIMIT $limit" );
  }

    if ( $keys )
        natcasesort($keys);
?>
```

What's the best way to overwrite the `meta_form` function? Would I have to create a plugin or something? I can't seem to find a clean answer. (p.s. I didn't write this code, I'm just the one fixing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `meta_form` function is not pluggable, and there are no hooks available, so, as hacking the core is not really recommended, you'll need another approach. The following is a jQuery solution. Put the code in the `functions.php` file of your theme, or in a plugin:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'so17239871_mod_metakeyselect' );
function so17239871_mod_metakeyselect()
{
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( ! ( 'post.php' == $pagenow && 'video_photo' == $post_type ) )
        return;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#metakeyselect > option").hide();
    jQuery("#metakeyselect > option[value^='tqmcf_']").show();
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot diggy! What exactly does this code do? I'm not too sure what `meta_form` does. And what's with the `^` in `value^='tqmcf_']`?

Comment: It'll hide every key in the select dropdown that does not start with `tqmcf_`, for the `video_photo` post type

Comment: Nice. How do I actually test this code? Where would I find a form that uses the original source code to load a form? In the admin section?

Comment: The form is used in the Custom Fields meta box, the part at the bottom, that has the "add custom field" button. You should see the meta box when creating or editing a `video_photo` post (or any normal post or page). By default, the dropdown displays every key that has ever been used on your WP site (except protected ones, starting with a `_`), with a limit of 30 items.

Comment: So according to this code, what would be different? If it is a video_photo, then should I not be seeing something?

Comment: You'll only see keys starting with `tqmcf_` in the select dropdown. NB: You should've added such a key at least once for it to show up. To test, create a (normal) test post or page, add several dummy keys and values, among which some keys starting with `tqmcf_`, and save or publish it. Then, create a `video_photo` post, and check which keys show up in the dropdown.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot diggy. Lifesaver

Comment: Hey diggy, so how does PHP know to return all of the last few lines in that function you wrote? You never write a `return` and surround the `<script>...</script>` in parentheses or anything.